# Calculating AVG and displaying top 10 score within a dog show database using MySql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I hope everyone is doing well during this pandemic.

I am a beginner and this is my first ever question so, I do apologise in advance for any error made.

I am being asked to calculate the top 10 average scores of dogs which, attended at least more than one competition. To display their name, breed and average score. I am struggling to implement such query any help would be more than appreciated.

To give you more an insight these are tables I am working with:

```
ENTRIES TABLE

id | competition_id | dog_id | score 
 1          15            1       3
 2           8            3       9
 3           8            1       7
 4          13            3       6
```

DOGS TABLE

```
id  |  name  |  breed_id 
 1     Kieran      1
 2     Alexa       2
 3     Leah        3
 4     Sonia       4
```

BREEDS TABLE

```
id  |  name
 1     Bulldog
 2     Chihuahua
 3     Terrier
 4     Mastiff
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the tables I used

```
CREATE TABLE Entries
    (`id` varchar(255), `competition_id` varchar(255), `dog_id` varchar(50), `score` varchar(50))
;
    
INSERT INTO Entries
    (`id`, `competition_id`, `dog_id`, `score`)
VALUES
    (1, 15, 1, 3),
    (2, 8, 3, 9),
    (3, 8, 1, 7),
    (4, 13, 3, 6)
;
                                                                  create table Dogs
 (`id` varchar(255), `name` varchar(255), `breed_id` varchar(255));
                                        
 insert into Dogs
        (`id`, `name`, `breed_id`)
values
    (1, 'Kieran', 1),
    (2, 'Alexa', 2),
    (3, 'Leah', 3) ,                                   
    (4, 'Sonia', 4);                                    

 create table Breeds
 (`id` varchar(255), `name` varchar(255));
                                        
 insert into Breeds
        (`id`, `name`)
values
    (1, 'Bulldog'),
    (2, 'Chihuahua'),
    (3, 'Terrier') ,                                   
    (4, 'Mastiff');
```

This query will show the average of only dogs that have scored in more than 1 competition, grouped by the dog breed.

```
select trainer, breed, score
from

(select Breeds.id as id, Dogs.name as trainer, Breeds.name as breed, avg(score) as score, count(Breeds.id) as count
from Entries
join Breeds on Entries.dog_id = Breeds.id
join Dogs on Breeds.id = Dogs.breed_id
group by breed
order by count)x
where count >= 2
group by breed

;
```

Results

```
+-------+--------+---+
| Kieran| Bulldog|  5|
+-------+--------+---+
|   Leah| Terrier|7.5|
+-------+--------+---+
```

Comment: That is a really a great way to implement it, thank you!